# Why this code using qsort function doesn't work in C?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, qsort

The sorting part:

```
      order = (struct order_s **) calloc(pm->len - q, sizeof(struct order_s*));

      for (i = 0; i < window_pos; ++i) {
              order[i] = (struct order_s *) malloc(sizeof(struct order_s));
              order[i]->pos = i;
              order[i]->good = good[i];
      }
      for (i = window_pos + q; i < pm->len; ++i)
      {
              order[i-q] = (struct order_s *) malloc(sizeof(struct order_s));
              order[i-q]->pos = i;
              order[i-q]->good = good[i];
      }
     qsort(order, pm->len - q, sizeof(struct order_s *), compare);
```

The compare function:

```
int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
        if ((((const struct order_s *)a)->good - ((const struct order_s *)b)->good) > 0)
                return 1;
        else
                return -1;
}
```

The stucture:

```
struct order_s {
  int pos;
  double good;
};
```

The values:

```
(gdb) p pm->len
$35 = 20
(gdb) p window_pos 
$36 = 1
(gdb) p q
$37 = 5
```

Before qsort():

```
(gdb) p *order[0]
$2 = {pos = 0, good = 1.3238653863672125}
(gdb) p *order[1]
$3 = {pos = 6, good = 0.96180564211148134}
(gdb) p *order[2]
$4 = {pos = 7, good = 1.0684181637005736}
(gdb) p *order[3]
$5 = {pos = 8, good = 0.92113662370476379}
```

After qsort():

```
(gdb) n
(gdb) p *order[0]
$6 = {pos = 0, good = 1.3238653863672125}
(gdb) p *order[1]
$7 = {pos = 6, good = 0.96180564211148134}
(gdb) p *order[2]
$8 = {pos = 7, good = 1.0684181637005736}
(gdb) p *order[3]
$9 = {pos = 8, good = 0.92113662370476379}
```

After the `qsort` function, the array of structure isn't sorted right and throws the segment fault later.

Comment: So what _does_ it do? Do the values look sane if you break inside `compare`?

Comment: Good test, just stick a printf inside your compare temporarily and look at the values which are getting compared.  You may be surprised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `compare()` function arguments are *pointers* to elements of the array. In this case, the elements of the array are `struct order*`, which means the arguments to `compare()` are `struct order**`, not `struct order*`.

Change to:

```
int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
    const struct order_s** aa = a;
    const struct order_s** bb = b;

    /* Can two 'order_s' instances never be equal ? */
    if ( (*aa)->good - (*bb)->good) > 0) return 1;
    else  return -1;
}
```

From the C99 standard section *7.20.5.2 The qsort function*:

> The contents of the array are sorted into ascending order according to a comparison
>   function pointed to by compar, **which is called with two arguments that point to the
>   objects being compared.** The function shall return an integer less than, equal to, or
>   greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

Comment: I think compare() still has a problem since it never returns 0.  It's conceivable (though unlikely) that qsort could call the comparator with pointers to the same object.  If it doesn't get 0 for that, you're gonna have a bad time.